# How to make multiple post requests with one button submit in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to convert my Jquery code to React. I have a form that when submitted creates multiple post requests to different sites and generates data for each site in a "card" corresponding to each site.

I made a component for the form. I also have a handleSubmit event but that only makes one fetch request. I want to make multiple fetch requests to multiple sites with one button click.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value
        })
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        fetch('/d2s2/L1000', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
    }
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
                                        <select id="memoryType" class="form-control firstList">

                                            <option value="drug" selected="selected">Drug</option>
                                            <option value="disease">Disease</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="drugInput" class="form-control search-input secondList" name="drug">

                                    </select>

                                </div>
                                <button class="form-control" id="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>

                            </form>

           </div>
        )
    }
```

this is my Jquery:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    var selectedOption = $('#memoryType option:selected').val();
    var text= $("#drugInput option:selected").val();
    var search = JSON.stringify({"input": text});
    $('.post-load').show();


    if (selectedOption.toLowerCase() == "drug") {
$.post("/d2s2/L1000", search, function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $(".card-1").html(data);
         $('.loader1').fadeOut('fast');
     }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".card-1 .card-text").html("No significant signatures found");
        $('.loader1').fadeOut('fast');
    })

     $.post("/d2s2/creeds_drugs", search, function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $(".card-2").html(data);
         $('.loader2').fadeOut('fast');
     }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".card-2 .card-text").html("No significant signatures found");
        $('.loader2').fadeOut('fast');
    })
     $.post("/d2s2/creeds_diseases", search, function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $(".card-3").html(data);
         $('.loader3').fadeOut('fast');
     }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".card-3 .card-text").html("No significant signatures found");
        $('.loader3').fadeOut('fast');
    })
     $.post("/d2s2/geneshot", search, function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $(".card-4").html(data);
         $('.loader4').fadeOut('fast');
     }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".card-4 .card-text").html("No significant signatures found");
        $('.loader4').fadeOut('fast');
    })
```

When I click on the submit button, all the cards should make post requests to their respective endpoints.

Comment: Can you please post the error you're receiving? Does the Jquery function get called? Some details would be helpful.

Comment: If you are using fetch/axios you can easily use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a state for each site you are requesting to and handle the requests separately like this:

```
state = {
    site1: {},
    site2: {}
}

requestSite1 = data => {
    fetch('site1Url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    }).then(res => this.setState({ site1: res }))
}

requestSite2 = data => {
    fetch('site2Url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    }).then(res => this.setState({ site2: res }))
}

async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
       input: event.target.value
    })
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    await this.requestSite1(data);
    await this.requestSite2(data);
}
```

and pass the states as props to your Card component like:

```
<Card site1Data={this.state.site1} site2Data={this.state.site2} />
```